# Android - Volley with GSON returns null list of values

Tags: android, json, gson, android-volley

I'm trying to do a simple Volley+GSON app, just pulling data from a JSON file online

JSON

```
{
  "tag": [
    {
      "id": "5",
      "name": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "name": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

I made a class as a model

```
public class obj {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

and this class too

```
public class objArray {
    public ArrayList<obj> results;

    public ArrayList<obj> getResults() {
        return results;
    }

}
```

Then I made this request

```
GsonRequest<objArray> jsObjRequest = new GsonRequest<objArray>(
                Request.Method.GET,
                _LINK,
                objArray.class, null,
                createSuccessListener(),
                createErrorListener());
```

So when I try to manipulate the output like this

```
response.getObjs().get(0).getName();
```

I get a null exception, seems that response.getObjs() returns null, response itself isn't null, just the array inside it, how can I fix this? Could the problem be within the JSON or the GsonRequest class?
Here is how I get the response in the GsonRequest class:

```
return Response.success(gson.fromJson(json,clazz),HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
```

Comment: You can try to look in your log if the request was done successfully and there's no error.

Comment: `result` != `tag`, so...

Comment: The request was done succesfully as far as I know, as I can read the URL contents, printing variable json (Which contains the string with data from the URL) provides me with the JSON content printed in entirety.

Comment: @njzk2 Woah! How could I not see that!? You won't believe how much time I spent fixing this.
Thanks man! This fixed it! Now I get the data indeed! 

Thanks again! If you want, add that as answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @njzk2  usahname  combine me and njzk2.

Comment: @tinysunlight I assume by combining you mean editing it in to your answer? I did that, I will mark it as the answer if the edit is accepted.

Comment: I always use basic Request.Now I know how to use a GsonRequest.

Comment: I appreciate your effort and attempt at answering me, if you didn't do a GsonRequest before as you imply, I hope somehow this question was of use to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Thanks to @njzk2 I was able to correct this, the problem lies in the objArray class, the variable holding the array is called "results", there is no element or array in the JSON file called results, that's what made the value null, my array in the JSON file was called "tag", thus the variable should have been named "tag".

```
public ArrayList<Tag> tag;
```

Note that the issue wasn't because of the lack of constructors or setters as @tinysunlight states, I didn't add them and the app still worked as intended.

---

```
return Response.success(gson.fromJson(new JSONObject(json).getString("tag"),clazz),HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
```

It is required by gson that
modal should have a  empty constructor and all getter and setter:

```
public class obj {
    private String id;
    private String name;
   public obj(){}
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name= name;
    }
}
```

Comment: not really. since `obj` extends `Object`, and since no other constructor is defined neither in `obj` nor in `Object`, the default empty constructor from `Object` is valid for `obj`

Comment: It's rquired by Gson!

Comment: No GSON tutorial indicated that.
Still wasn't the problem, and the app worked without it thanks to @njzk2 answer.
Thanks for the answer :).